# In Core Data, what is the URI property type on the NSManaged object supposed to be used for?

Tags: ios, swift, url, core-data

[image]

1. Why would you need the URI type?
2. What is the equivalent Swift object type for a URI property?
3. Would I store a URL in this property?
4. I'm doubtful that I would ever want to store the URI for another managed object in this way, but is it related?

Also, a link to any Apple docs that describe the usage would be helpful.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In the [WWDC 2017 "What's New in Core Data" session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/210/), one of the slides indicates:

[image: New Attribute Types]

> Why would you need the URI type?

To store a URL.

> What is the equivalent Swift object type for a URI property?

The Swift equivalent of `NSURL` is `URL`.

> Would I store a URL in this property?

That is the purpose of the type.

> I'm doubtful that I would ever want to store the URI for another managed object in this way, but is it related?

Possible, but probably not a good idea. A relationship would be better. Still, there might be cases where it makes sense to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use URI to store URL of image, audio, video or any other resource. In case, you store images on the device in files, you can use URL of the file path.

Comment: Could you add more information to your post please?

Comment: "It is better, however, if you are able to store BLOBs as resources on the file system and to maintain links (such as URLs or paths) to those resources. You can then load a BLOB as and when necessary." https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Performance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH25-SW1