# Storing an data item's file extension in Core Data: plain string or other flavor of data Type?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working on the data model for an app I'm building that will use CoreData.  As part of that process, the app includes a function that will iterate through a series of MP3 files to populate the database.

The data model at the moment is:

```
var metadataArray = [(fileName: String, title: String, artist: String,
    duration: String, fileExtension: String)]()
```

Note that in order for the app to later access those files, I'm storing the file name and the file extension.  Since the path to the app's Documents folder isn't known at build time, my thought was to include code that programmatically locates the Documents folder.  Then, when it's time to access a file, use the stub path to the Documents folder and tack on the filename String and fileExtension String using `.appendPathComponent()` to generate a URL from the three components.

My question feels kind of esoteric, but it seems like the right time to ask it:

**Q: Swift provides a method to assemble URLs from *strings,* but in the data model declaration, is there any special data Type that's more appropriate for storing file names and file extensions than just plain Strings?**

I'm guessing the answer is no -- that Strings are fine, given all the methods Swift provides to assemble full URLs from Strings.   But since Swift allows you to declare a full URL as a data type, I thought it was worth asking if there's some sort of a data type more suitable for **components** of a URL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46909519/2303865

Comment: thanks for the link -- a file extension is not a full URL, though.   I haven't tried it (yet!) but I suspect that entering, e.g. .mp3 in a datatype intended to be a URL would throw an "invalid URL" error, no?

Comment: You can just add a computed property to your struct that would compose the URL for you when needed

Comment: if you don't pass invalid characters for the file path (name or extension)  it will always be a valid URL  but it doesn't mean that the file will exist at that location